# Removing rows having nonfrequent tags in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of about 1000000 rows and due to my computation limit i cannot take all the rows from the dataset.  My dataset contains atleast 60000 tags but i dont need all of those tags. I just need to select top 200 tags or so from the dataset and keep only the  rows which consist the tags and discard the others.

```
| question  | tags |
| --------- | --------------- |
| question1 | ['symfony','assestic'] |
| question2 | ['java','containers','kubernetes'] |
| question3 | ['python','pelican'] |
| question4 | ['python','api','oath','python-requests'] |
| question5 | ['google-api','google-cloud-storage'] |
```

I tried using `CountVectorizer` but it didnt work out for me. Is there any pandas or python tricks to solve it ?

Comment: You could filter the rows before creating the dataframe. How are you trying to load it currently? (Specificaly: is it a csv file, or is it a database tables or... ?  )

Comment: It is from a csv file. I got the solution now though

Answer (score 0):

You can apply pandas.Series.value_counts in your column of interest